# I am trying to find an average of input values in dictionary using for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    student_marks = {}
    for _ in range(n):
        name, *line = input().split()
        scores = list(map(float, line))
        student_marks[name] = scores
    query_name = input()
    sum=0
    if query_name in student_marks:
        for i in student_marks[query_name]:
            sum+=i
        x=float(sum/len(scores))
        print("%.2f"%x)
```

I had done this but want to execute in less number of lines

Comment: Try not to use ``sum`` as a variable name because is a ''native'' python method name.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your summing loop with:

```py
if query_name in student_marks:
  total = sum(student_marks[query_name])
  mean = total / len(student_marks[query_name])
  print("%.2f" % mean)
```

You could also precompute the average for each student and store it in that dictionary to begin with:

```py
for _ in range(n):
  name, *line = input().split()
  record = {'scores': list(map(float, line))}
  record['total'] = sum(record['scores'])
  record['n'] = len(record['scores'])
  student_marks[name] = record
```

Alternatively:

```py
for _ in range(n):
  name, *line = input().split()
  scores = list(map(float, line))
  student_marks[name] = {
    'scores': scores,
    'total': sum(scores),
    'n': len(scores)
  }
```

Then your query would simply look like this:

```py
def query(name):
  if name in student_marks:
   record = student_marks[name]
   return record['total'] / record['n']
```

Comment: Sure, I will do